# C++/Qt libraries for GIS programming

Tags: c++, gis, qt

I want to start programming GIS applications for simple composing of maps by vector and raster data using C++ and Qt.
Which libraries your can recommend?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/are-recommendations-for-programming-tutorials-resources-on-topic

Comment: Asking for tutorials is unfortunately off topic here, so I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is a great idea. I know that satellite imagery is sometimes in different color combinations. Depending on the encryption it could use a color combination. Similar to the human eye. You can DM for more intel on. On iOs objective c but ERDAS IMAGINE is what you probably are trying to create. I hope that this helps